# Xcode 6.3 App Submission Failed for iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, submission

I am currently using XCode 6.3. My project is using `CocoaPods`.

I have set Deployment Target to be iOS7.0 for both my project and Pods. Also, I have validated my archive and it was successful.

But, when I clicked "Submit to App Store...", it failed with the following errors.

> 1. "Invalid Info.plist value. The value for the key ‘MinimumOSVersion’ in bundle ActionSheetPicker_3_0.framework is invalid. The minimum value is 8.0"
> 2. "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at ‘AHKActionSheet’ does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding app with the latest Xcode version."

Please help!!! I really need my app to work for iOS 7+, because I am from Myanmar and lots of people here are still using iOS 7. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: They exactly said what to do :) Just do it.

Comment: This would likely crash on iOS 7, you should always test with iOS versions you intend to release on before upload to the app store.  As a minimum, download and test with the iOS7 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears because you are using the [`ActionSheetPicker`](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0) framework which apparently requires iOS 8.

So you should review your ActionSheetPicker framework. Is there a version which supports iOS 7? If not you should use another framework.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You can add comment or provide solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

As Dung says ActionSheetPicker requires iOS8.  You have several options:

1. Weakly link the ActionSheetPicker framework, and use an alternative for iOS7
2. Fix (or ask developer to fix) ActionSheetPicker so it works with iOS7 (according to his Readme it should work with iOS 5.1.1+).  It is likely only the case of changing deployment target of the framework and rebuilding.
3. Use a different library for this purpose, or code this functionality yourself.

Always test on the target iOS versions before you release to apple!